# development.log not logging after deleting file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I deleted the contents of the `development.log` file on my server because it was getting big. Then after it was empty, I noticed that it stopped logging entirely. So I deleted the file completely and it still continued not to log. Then I remade the file manually and still no luck. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try restarting your rails application server. Looks like something you did broke the pipe between the application and the log.

Comment: I too restarted the server but the same problem persist. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

`rake log:clear` , helps you clear your log files